# Finding the Gain Equation of a Boost Converter with LC Resonator

Tags: capacitor, power-electronics, inductor, boost, resonance

I am trying to implement the following [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/Appnotes/00002265B.pdf) circuit in a project. The circuit is a boost converter with an LC circuit resonator (L3 and C4 resonate). I am trying to find the DC transfer function equation of the circuit, but I am currently getting that the input voltage (VBOOST) is equal to the output voltage (Vout).

Circuit from the datasheet: (ignore the LHS circuit, boost converter is on the right)
[image]

Redrawn circuit from datasheet: (C3 and R11 are not included since they are marked as DNP)
[image]

Comment: The diode and switching will make linear analysis hard to analyze, a gain equation won't make sense in this case.

Comment: You want a small-signal gain or a dc transfer equation linking \$V_{out}\$ to \$V_{in}\$? These are two different values.

Comment: How about a simulation?

Comment: @Verbal Kint I am trying to find the DC transfer function

Comment: Does a quick simulation show that your circuit and its components values confirm that you have the wanted boost effect at least?

Comment: What is not clear are the  source impedance of Vboost, the PFM frequency and the output specs for DC and AC. (i.e. da specs) your test results are not given for each node. Too much missing info.  C5 is your DC output and the Piezo is AC only, not 150R

Answer (score 0):

Your equivalent circuit will only match input voltage for DC. But the nebulizer piezo is AC coupled, so C5 is your DC output transfer function while AC is resonated to the Piezo if matched properly.

Suggestion, AC couple your equivalent 150R load